# How to dynamically delete an item from a dynamically created list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

How do I delete from my dynamically created list?

This is a sample of what I want:
https://jsfiddle.net/jessica_mather123/8vgu5bqk/8/

How the list is created:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        var value = $("#id :selected").text();
        var value1 = $("#id :selected").text();
        var value2 = $("#id").val();
        $("#ul").after('<li style="display:list-item; padding:5px;border:2px solid black" name="name[]"><strong>attribute 1:</strong> ' + value + ', <strong>Attribute 2:</strong> ' + value1 + ', <strong>Attribute 3:</strong> ' + value2 + '</li>');
```

What I used to try and delete from the list:

```
    $('#ul li').on('click',function(e){
        $('this').remove();
    });
```

Everything seems to look right from what I've seen, but I still don't know why it is not deleting?

Comment: use `$(document).on('click','#ul li', function(e){` delegate the click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ul li', function(e){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

And change

```
$("#ul").after('<li style="display:list-item; padding:5px;border:2px solid black" name="name[]"><strong>attribute 1:</strong> ' + value + ', <strong>Attribute 2:</strong> ' + value1 + ', <strong>Attribute 3:</strong> ' + value2 + '</li>');
```

to

```
$("#ul").append('<li style="display:list-item; padding:5px;border:2px solid black" name="name[]"><strong>attribute 1:</strong> ' + value + ', <strong>Attribute 2:</strong> ' + value1 + ', <strong>Attribute 3:</strong> ' + value2 + '</li>');
```

jQuery will miss the dynamically created element the way you add event listeners.

#### [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tznnd5jz/)

Comment: I switched it to the way you have put in the example but it still isn't working.

Comment: @JessicaMather, can you create a fiddle for the problem? I suspect in `.after()` because that will append the `li` after `#ul`

Comment: I put my fiddle above

Comment: @JessicaMather, this is the updated and working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tznnd5jz/

Answer (score 2):

1) First main problem is here:

```
$('#ul').after();
```

You are appending li after ul that's why listener had problems.

i changed your code like this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

$('#button').click(function() {
        var value = "test1";
        var value1 = "test2";
        var value2 = "test3"

        var row = '<li style="display:list-item; padding:5px;border:2px solid black"><strong>attribute 1:</strong> ' + value + ', <strong>Attribute 2:</strong> ' + value1 + ', <strong>Attribute 3:</strong> ' + value2 + '</li>';
        $("#ul").append(row);

       $('#ul li').on('click',function(e){
        $(this).remove();
    });


});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL7s4yca/)